# CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Okta SignInWidget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, okta

I am incorporating Okta into my React application. I created a Login page with the SignInWidget and it actually looks like the POST request sent with the login data is sending correctly with status 200 to 'https://{oktaDomain}/api/v1/authn. However, immediately following this request is GET request from {oktaDomain}/oath2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration with the following error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://{domain}.okta.com/oath2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

From similar questions on here, the only answer I can find is to ensure that localhost:3000 is accepted as a trusted source within Okta API and it is. I also get the following errors in the console immediately afterward:

[image]

Here is my code for the SignInWidget:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import OktaSignIn from '@okta/okta-signin-widget';
import '@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/css/okta-sign-in.min.css';
import appConfig from '../../app.config';

export default class OktaSignInWidget extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        this.widget = new OktaSignIn({
            baseUrl: this.props.baseUrl,
            el: '#widget',
            authParams: {
                pkce: true,
                issuer: appConfig.issuer
            }
        });
        
        this.widget.renderEl({el}, this.props.onSuccess, this.props.onError);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.widget.remove();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Login Page:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import OktaSignInWidget from './OktaSignInWidget';
import withOktaAuth from '@okta/okta-react/dist/withOktaAuth';
import Navbar from '../Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer'

export default withOktaAuth(
    class Login extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        
            this.state = {
                 authenticated: null
            }

            this.checkAuthentication();
        }


        checkAuthentication = async () => {
            const authenticated = this.props.authState.isAuthenticated;
            if (authenticated !== this.state.authenticated) {
                this.setState({authenticated})
            }
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
            this.checkAuthentication();
        };

        onSuccess = (res) => {
            if (res.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                return this.props.authService.redirect({
                    sessionToken: res.session.token
                });
            }
        }

        onError = (err) => {
            console.log('error logging in', err);
        }

        render() {
            return this.state.authenticated ?
                <Redirect to={{pathname: '/'}} /> :
                <div className="login">
                    <Navbar />
                    <OktaSignInWidget
                        baseUrl={this.props.baseUrl}
                        onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
                        onError={this.onError}/> 
                    <Footer />                   
                </div>

        }
    }
)
```

Here is the App

```
...
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginCallback from '@okta/okta-react/dist/LoginCallback';
import SecureRoute from '@okta/okta-react/dist/SecureRoute';
import ProfilePage from './Components/ProfilePage';
import Security from '@okta/okta-react/dist/Security';
import appConfig from './app.config';
import Login from './Components/BusinessAuth/Login';



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  
    this.state = {
       
    }
  }

  onAuthRequired = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/login');
  }
  
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Security
            issuer={appConfig.issuer}
            client_id={appConfig.client_id}
            redirect_uri={appConfig.redirect_uri}
            onAuthRequired={this.onAuthRequired}
            pkce={true}
          >
            <Switch>
                ...
                <Route path='/login' render={() => <Login baseUrl={appConfig.url} />}  />
                <Route component={LoginCallback} path='/implicit/callback'  />
                <SecureRoute component={ProfilePage} path='/profile' />
                <Route component={LandingPage} path='/' />
            </Switch>
          </Security>
        </div>
      );
    }    
  }


export default withRouter(App);
```

What are these errors and how can I correct them? Given that CORS should already be accepted from localhost:3000, I cannot figure out why the initial POST request seems to work but the GET request assigning a session token is not working.

Comment: Do you have `http://localhost:3000` listed as a trusted origin in API > Trusted Origins?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the server to accept requests from a particular origin. It is just a pre-flight request that is sent by browsers to check if the server allows the specific origin to be served. For debugging purposes, you can use the `cors-everywhere` prefix. This is an intermediate server which makes request on our behalf and sets appropriate headers so that our browser can accept it.

Let us say your URL is

`https://{domain}.okta.com/oath2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration`,

just prefix it with

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

like

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://{domain}.okta.com/oath2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration`

and then make your request.

Comment: I actually have my express routes handled to accept requests from anywhere because of this. I thought that may be the problem, so I added installed express-cors and used app.use(cors()) above my routes. However, the error message seems to imply that the issue is on the {domain}.okta.com side rather than the localhost.